# Breaking Up A List Using Values As Breakpoints?

Tags: python, list

I have a list that contains a few values, each followed by a number of Nones:

```
['Apple', None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Orange', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Pear', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Banana', None, None]
```

I want an output like this, that breaks up the list into separates lists each with the non-None value as breakpoints:

```
['Apple', None, None, None, None, None, None] 
['Orange', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None] 
['Pear', None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
['Banana', None, None]
```

I am scratching my head as to how to do it.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: The second code snippet is the output I want. Four seperate lists.

Comment: I mean, Why do you want this output?

Comment: Because eventually I want to replace all the Nones after "Apple" with "Apple" until "Orange" (and then all the Nones after Orange with Orange until Pear, etc etc) then repeat until the end.

Answer (score 2):

You said you wanted to replace the None's with the latest non-None value.  I'll skip the "how do I split" question, and answer the "replacing" question:

```
def fill_nones(seq):
    last = None
    for val in seq:
        if val is not None:
            last = val
        yield last
```

Now you can make a new list with:

```
filled = list(fill_nones(old_list))
```

Comment: Wow this is great. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a better way with list comprehensions but something like this will split the original list into a list of smaller lists as long as the first value isn't None.

```
def splitlist(listin):
    newlist = []
    for val in listin:
        if val != None:
            newlist.append([val])
        else:
            newlist[-1].append(None)
    return newlist
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
x = ['Apple', None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Orange', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Pear', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Banana', None, None]
output = []
sub = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    cur = x[i]
    if i > 0:
            if cur != None:
                    output.append(sub)
                    sub = [cur]
            elif i >= len(x)-1:
                    sub.append(cur)
                    output.append(sub)
                    sub = [cur]
            else:
                    sub.append(cur)
    else:
            sub.append(cur)
```

Which yields:

```
>>> output
[['Apple', None, None, None, None, None, None], ['Orange', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], ['Pear', None, None, None, None, None, None, None], ['Banana', None, None]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem using two new auxiliary lists.

The code looks like this:

```
def fill_list(seq):
    list_aux_1 = list()
    list_out   = list()

    for item in seq:
        if isinstance(item, str):
            list_out.append(list_aux_1)
            list_aux_1 = list()
        list_aux_1.append(item)
    else:
        list_out.append(list_aux_1)
        list_out = list_out[1:]
    return list_out
```

to use only

```
seq = ['Apple', None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Orange', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Pear', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Banana', None, None]
print fill_list(seq)
```